# Volume of 3D convex hull of small point sets all on the hull

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, computational-geometry

I have a question that is similar to [this one asked before](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2771/is-there-a-special-algorithm-for-computing-the-convex-hull-ordering-when-the-can) except in 3D, and I only need the volume, not the actual shape of the hull.

More precisely, I'm given a small set of points (say, 10-15) in 3D, all of which are known to lie on the convex hull of the point set (so they all "matter" and define the hull). I only want to compute the volume of the hull, I don't care about computing the actual polyhedron. Is there an efficient algorithm to do this?

Comment: You know the points are vertices of the polyhedron.  Do you know the faces (polygons on the hull)?  If so you can compute the volume rather easily (as a sum of "cone" volumes).

Comment: A lazy way would be triangulating first, then adding up the volumes of the tetrahedra (very easy to compute).

Comment: @hardmath: No. I know that if I knew the facet shapes it would be easy.

Comment: @Shuhao Cao: Is there a simple triangulation algorithm for this special case? Generally 3D tetrahedralization algorithms are quite complicated, and I expect to need to solve this problem thousands or millions of times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd be surprised if you can beat the suggestion of Shuhao Cao: compute the hull and then the volume once you have a triangulation of the hull. You could compute the hull with the $O(n^2)$ incremental algorithm, or the gift-wrapping algorithm. If you really want easy code, you can simply write an $n^4$ loop over all possible triangles to see if they are on the hull. For $n=15$, this is still pretty fast, and you can easily implement shortcuts. Once you have all the triangle faces, then pick one vertex $v$ and make a tetrahedron with each triangle $T$ and $v$. Its volume is a $4 \times 4$ determinant in the vertex coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

From Komei Fukuda's [Polyhedral Computation FAQ](ftp://ftp.ifor.math.ethz.ch/pub/fukuda/reports/polyfaq040618.pdf):

> **2.23 Is there any efficient algorithm to compute the volume of a
>   convex polytope in $R^d$?**
>
> It is known that computing the volume of a V-polytope (or H-polytope)
>   is #P-hard, see [DF88] and [Kha93]. There are theoretically efficient
>   randomized algorithms to approximate the volume of a convex body
>   [LS93] but no implementation seems to be available. There is a
>   comparative study [BEF00] of various volume computation algorithms for
>   convex polytopes. It indicates that there is no single algorithm that
>   works well for many different types of polytopes.
>
> [[DF88]](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0217060?journalCode=smjcat)
>    M.E. Dyer and A.M. Frieze. The complexity of computing the
>   volume of a polyhedron. *SIAM J. Comput.*, 17:967-974, 1988.
>
> [Kha93] L.G. Khachiyan. Complexity of polytope volume computation. In
>   J. Pach, editor, *New Trends in Discrete and Computational Geometry*,
>   pages 91-101. Springer Verlag, Berlin, 1993.
>
> [LS93] L. Lovasz and M. Simonovits. Random walks in a convex body and
>   an improved volume algorithm.
>   *Random structures & algorithms*, 4:359-412, 1993.
>
> [BEF00] B. Bueler,  A. Enge, and K. Fukuda. Exact volume computation
>   for convex polytopes: A practical study. In G. Kalai and G. M.
>   Ziegler, editors, *Polytopes - Combinatorics and Computation*,
>   DMV-Seminar 29, pages 131-154. Birkhauser,
>   2000.

This may seem to bury the specifics of the 3D problem among difficulties
of higher dimensions, despite the title of the Dyer and Frieze paper.  From their Abstract: "We show that computing the volume of a polyhedron given either as a list of facets or as a list of vertices is as hard as computing the permanent of a matrix."

A 1991 paper by Jim Lawrence, [Polytope Volume Computation](http://fma2.math.uni-magdeburg.de/~henk/lectures/konvexgeometrie%20analytische%20aspekte/seminar/lawrence&polytope%20volume%20computation.pdf), can be read online and has some references for the specifically 3D case.  He writes, "The method in the present paper avoids triangulation of $P$ or of its boundary."  Also the algorithm described in that paper seems appropriate for your situation as it expresses "the volume of $P$ as a sum of numbers $N_v$, one for each vertex $v$ of $P$. These numbers are easy to compute, so the difficulty of the procedure is mainly enumerating the vertices of $P$."  The difficulty probably translates in your situation to finding an expression for $P$ as the solution of a system of linear inequalities $P = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : Ax \le b \}$.

If you already know such an "intersection of half-spaces" expression for $P$, then perhaps it will permit a fairly fast computation.

Answer (score 2):

A small test in MATLAB, for number of vertex $N = 100$, each component is a uniform random number in $[0,1]$:

```
N = 100;
p=rand(N,3);
tic;
T = delaunayTri(p(:,1),p(:,2),p(:,3));
t = T.Triangulation;
e1 = p(t(:,2),:)-p(t(:,1),:);
e2 = p(t(:,3),:)-p(t(:,1),:);
e3 = p(t(:,4),:)-p(t(:,1),:);
V = abs(dot(cross(e1,e2,2),e3,2))/6;
Vol = sum(V);
time_elapse = toc;
```

Result:

```
time_elapse =
              0.014807
Vol =
      0.67880219135839
```

I would say it is reasonably fast, if you wanna run it $10^6$ times, it only takes less than 3 hours. Here is what it is like:

[image: convhull]

Also I want to mention that in Professor O'Rourke's post he mentioned using determinant to compute tetrahedra's volumes, yet here I prefer using triple product. It is a naturally vectorized operation, more scalable than the built-in routine of determinant (or you can expand a $4\times 4$ determinant by hand :p). Here is another test for $N=10^5$, the result is

```
time_elapse =
              3.244278
Vol =
     0.998068316875714
```

with tetrahedra number $\approx 7\times 10^5$. Notice the total volume is pretty closed to $1$ for there are too many points clustered in $[0,1]^3$.

Comment: BTW the test is done on my old 2007 Core 2 T61p.